# Null reference in lambda max count

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

```
 Public Class Inventory
        Public Property Productcode As String
        Public Property lstattribute As List(Of Attribute)
 End Class
 Public Class Attribute
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property value As String 
 End Class
```

I have a list of inventory items. 
I am trying to get the max count of attributelist in the inventory list

I used this code

```
oLsInventory.OrderByDescending(Function(c) c.AttributeList.Count).FirstOrDefault().AttributeList.Count
```

But if my attribute list null. The lambda throws null reference.
Is there any way to check for null reference in lambda ? Or is there a better way to rewrite the above linq query ?

Thanks 
Jothish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it working.
Before ordering I filtered the null objects..then ran the count on top of that list.

```
oLsInventory.FindAll(Function(c) c.AttributeList IsNot Nothing).OrderByDescending(Function(c) c.AttributeList.Count).Select(Function(c) c.AttributeList.Count).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would place the FirstOrDefault at the very end by adding a Select like so:

```
oLsInventory.OrderByDescending(Function(c) c.AttributeList.Count).Select(Function(c) c.AttributeList.Count).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Thanks Aducci..but because attributelist is nothing the above code was throwing error..I got it working by using -               oLsInventory.FindAll(Function(c) c.AttributeList IsNot Nothing).OrderByDescending(Function(c) c.AttributeList.Count).Select(Function(c) c.AttributeList.Count).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: @JoR - Glad you fiqured it out. Post your solution as an answer and accept it. This will help people with a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Move `FirstOrDefault` to the very back and use `Select` to map your list of Inventories to a list of attribute counts.

```
 ' Returns 0 if the list is empty
 Dim max = oLsInventory.OrderByDescending(Function(c) c.AttributeList.Count) _
           .Select(Function(c) AttributeList.Count).FirstOrDefault()
```

Another option is to:

- map the list of inventories to a list of attribute counts
- add `Integer.MinValue` to the list
- execute `Max()`:

  ```
  ' Returns Integer.MinValue if oLsInventory is empty
  Dim maxValue = oLsInventory.Select(Function(c) AttributeList.Count) _
                 .Union(New Integer() {Integer.MinValue}).Max()
  ```